# I updated Sony Xperia Sola (MT27i) and it do not work properly

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 2.3-gingerbread, updates, sony-xperia

I have `Sony Xperia Sola (MT27i).` I updated it from android version `2.3 (gingerbread)` to `4.0 (ice-cream-sandwich)`, and now my phone can not work normally; Its RAM is always full and it need very long time to do something, especial when I need call, send messages or play something.

Please someone advised me something, what can I do?

Comment: Was this an official update from your carrier (or Sony,) or was it a custom ROM?

Comment: @Chahk This was official update